# How to display a custom throw statement

Tags: java

So I have a method that is taking userInput at the keyboard to plug into a calculator. Obviously I can't have strings or negative numbers put into the input field so I have all three inputs encased in a try block to catch any exception. Problem is I am trying to throw an exception when input is wrong INSIDE the try block but when an exception is caught it displays the message of the try-catch block. Here is the code:

```
public static void calculateTips()
{
//Varibles
int tipPercentage = 0;
int partySize = 0;
double billAmount = 0.0;
//Variable to loop through try catch blocks 
int x = 0;

String yesOrNo;

 boolean choice;
//Decimal Format 
DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("$###,##0.00");

//Declare object
TipCalculator bill;

//Create Scanner object
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

do
{
  //Fill values for tip calculator from user 
  System.out.println("Enter the bill amount: ");

  try
  {

     billAmount = userInput.nextDouble();

     if(billAmount < 0)

      throw new Exception("Bill amount can not be negative. Please try again."); 



     System.out.println("Enter your desired tip percentage (20 equals 20%): ");
     tipPercentage = userInput.nextInt();

     if(tipPercentage < 0)
       throw new Exception("Tip percentage can not be negative. Please try again."); 

     System.out.println("Enter the size of your party: ");
     partySize = userInput.nextInt();

      if(partySize < 0)
        throw new Exception("Party Size can not be negative. Please try again."); 


  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again." + "\n");
   calculateTips();
  }
```

I have tried using InputMismatchType as an overall exception but had no luck in getting that working. As you can see I am trying to display those custom messages in the try block. If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: Can you explain `no luck in getting that working`?  What isn't working?  What do you see and what do you want to see instead?

Comment: If I unerstand correctly, you want to print the message of the exception you catch. So... do that instead of printing `"Invalid Input. Please try again."`.

Comment: @markspace When I put in a value, like a string value when it should be a double, I get the default "Invalid input" from my overall catch statement instead of the custom exception I need to display.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you catch `Exception` this means that any Exception (and subclasses of excption) will be caught in the same block, a solution is to create a custom exception and catch it early than exception leaving other exceptions to the default you have such:

```
try  {
  billAmount = userInput.nextDouble();
   if(billAmount < 0)
      throw new MyException("Bill amount can not be negative. Please try again."); 
} catch(MyException e) { // catch a specific exception first
 System.out.println("Exception" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
} catch(Throwable e) { // get all others to fall here, also using Throwable here cause it is also super for Exception and RuntimeException
 System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again." + "\n");
 calculateTips();
}
// and declare in the scope of class
class MyException extends Exception {
     MyException(String message) { super(message); }
}
```

Also, another solution, is to catch the specific ArithmeticExceptions and ParseExceptions in the catchs and use a third one for your specific error (extending one is still suggested in both cases)